# Change font on Tab mid caption

Tags: delphi, fonts, caption

I'm using Delphi 7.

I want to indicate on the tab caption that the page related to the tab has content.  If there is content in the dbgrid on the page I want to follow the caption with a winding, represented with the letter n which shows up as a box.  So now instead of the caption reading 'Paient History' it would read 'Patient History ' + a little filled box.

Since the symbol is the letter 'n' with a font type of wingding I want to change the font type in the middle of the caption and add the letter n resulting in a small filled box at the end of the caption.

```
Tabsheet.caption := 'Patient History ' + changefonttypetowinding + 'n'.
```

Doable?

Comment: Things like this work so great with Unicode (Delphi 2009+).

Comment: Recommendation: Unless you're prepared to move to Unicode, use Andreas's simple suggestion of using *. If this is a contract job, tell them that they can have the black square looking good if they pay you to migrate to DelphiXE (give estimate).  They can also have it if they don't mind it "looking funny", with the owner-draw solution. Or they can have the * right now, for no additional cost.

Answer (score 6):

You're into owner-draw territory here and that's not totally trivial to do well once you take into account themes.  If you do go that route then I wouldn't bother with Wingdings, I'd just paint the box will a `TCanvas.FillRect`.

Personally I'd look into a Unicode Delphi and use U+2587 (▇) or one of its friends.

Comment: Should be two answers, as there are two entirely different solutions here. And I would have upvoted each... ;->

Comment: @Chris Very nice of you to say so! Actually I wouldn't consider anything other than U+2587!

Answer (score 3):

Since you are not using a Unicode-enabled version of Delphi, you are restricted to owner-drawing or the "ANSI" character set, as pointed out by David. (My suggestion is that you upgrade to Delphi 2009+. Unicode is the best thing that has ever happened to the digital world. With Unicode, you get tens of thousands of characters (in theory, per font!) instead of 127 or 255. This includes all sorts of languages as well as technical and mathematical symbols and various dingbats. There is even a benzene ring: U+232C BENZENE RING: ⌬)

Now let's assume that upgrading is not possible. Then, if I were you, I would use the historical "standard character" for this purpose, namely, the asterisk (*). I recommend this very strongly in your case.

If you relly, relly, want a black square, then you must do owner-drawing. You might do it like this:

```
// Please don't do this -- see comments below
procedure TForm1.PageControl1DrawTab(Control: TCustomTabControl;
  TabIndex: Integer; const Rect: TRect; Active: Boolean);
const
  Padding = 8;
  SqSize = 6;
var
  capt: string;
  r: TRect;
begin
  capt := TTabControl(Control).Tabs[TabIndex];
  r := Rect;
  r.Left := r.Left + Padding;
  DrawText(Control.Canvas.Handle, capt, length(capt), r, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_LEFT or DT_VCENTER or DT_END_ELLIPSIS);
  r.Left := r.Right - Padding - SqSize;
  r.Right := r.Left + SqSize;
  r.Top := (r.Bottom - r.Top - SqSize) div 2;
  r.Bottom := r.Top + SqSize;
  FillRect(Control.Canvas.Handle, r, GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
end;
```

Notice, however, that this will disable visual themes! It will look dreadful! Please don't do this!

Comment: +1 I knew you wouldn't be able to resist the tempation of writing some owner-draw code!!

Comment: +1 for the code. I'd add an additional vote or two if I could for the last line of your answer, though. Owner-draw is *ugly* with themes enabled unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: @David, you know me! But this time it is more to illustrate why you *shouldn't* attempt to owner-draw it.